# Automatic Login is greyed out

Tags: macos

I am trying to setup automatic login on my machine.

1. I have FileVault off.
2. I am not using a icloud account.

Still the automatic login is greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure automatic login is not blocked from security settings.

Comment: Can you give more specific directions about how to do that?